# Parse string with tokenizer and rewrite toString

Tags: java, string

the problem is that if i type minus `-` sign in the valueOf parameter then i get `invalidArgumentexception` because the created quaternion is not equal to the created quaternion due to the toString method, can anyone help me to modify the toString or the valueOf methods so that the `String s` parameter will accept `-` signs before each double value.

```
 //constructor
public Quaternion (double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
    this.d = d;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append(a);

    if(b>=0){
        sb.append("+"+b+"i");
    }
    if(b < 0){
        sb.append(" "+b+"i");
    }
    if(c>=0){
        sb.append("+"+c+"j");
    }
    if(c < 0){
        sb.append("" + c +"j");
    }
    if(d>=0){
        sb.append("+"+ d +"k");
    }
    if(d < 0){
        sb.append(""+ d +"k");
    }
    return sb.toString(); 

}

/** Conversion from the string to the quaternion. 
 * Reverse to <code>toString</code> method.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if string s does not represent 
 *     a quaternion (defined by the <code>toString</code> method)
 * @param s string of form produced by the <code>toString</code> method
 * @return a quaternion represented by string s
 */
public static Quaternion valueOf (String s) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "-+ijk ");
    ArrayList fields = new ArrayList();
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        fields.add(st.nextToken());

         //System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }   
    double r = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(0));
    double t = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(1));
    double y = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(2));
    double u = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(3));
    Quaternion q = new Quaternion(r, t, y, u);

    if(!q.toString().equals(s)) {
        System.out.println("Error in input" + q);
    }
    return q; 
}
```

Comment: What's the input that you pass to valueOf method?

Comment: `valueOf("1.2-2.2i+3.0j-4.0k").toString();`

Comment: Your question doesn't correspond to the title. You want to parse your specific string, probably with the tokenizer, and rewrite your toString accordingly. Hence "-" from me.

Comment: Yes thats what im looking for sry for the misunderstand.

Answer (score 1):

The data members are doubles, so the signs should be associated with the values, not set in the `toString()` method.

I'd make all those data members final.  You quaternion is immutable then: inherently thread safe.

Learn how to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly from Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" [chapter 3](http://basen.oru.se/kurser/java/2007-2008-p2/texter/effective-java-kapitel/Chapter3.pdf).

Comment: Yes i know, but it can also be done by looking for the signs in string for example if the input contains - sign it will append - sign before the double value so that the quaternion would equal

Answer (score 0):

Double.parseDouble(String xyz) method will not parse single characters like "-", "+", "i", "j", "K". Thats why u are getting invalidArgumentexception.

Double.parseDouble(String xyz) only parsevalid floating point numbers repesented in string format like

"+11.12" or "-32.11" or anything which can be converted to double number.

Change the logic like below,

```
Remove the stringTokenizer logic

ArrayList fields = new ArrayList();
fields .add("12.11");
fields.add("23.12");
fileds.add("-123.01");
fields.add("-67.1");
double r = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(0));
double t = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(1));
double y = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(2));
double u = Double.parseDouble((String) fields.get(3));
Quaternion q = new Quaternion(r, t, y, u);
```

Comment: If i remove the tokenizer then i cant get theese double values from the string